# Find the minimum of $\frac{32a^{3}}{(b+3c)^{3}} + \frac{32b^3}{(a+3c)^{3}} - \frac{\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}}{c}$ for $(a+c)(b+c)=4c^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, maxima-minima

This is a problem in my exam and I can't find the solution using elementary inequality knowledge. Can anyone here help me solve this. Thanks

> $a,b,c $ are positive real numbers which satisfy $(a+c)(b+c) = 4c^{2}$. Find the minimum of this expression:
> $$P = \frac{32a^{3}}{(b+3c)^{3}} + \frac{32b^3}{(a+3c)^{3}} - \frac{\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}}{c}$$

Thanks so much.

Comment: I wonder your exam in view of [your other questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/38024/le-duc-quang?tab=questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We begin with the observation  that the change $a=xc, b=yc$ reduces the problem under consideration to the two-dimensional optimization problem 
$$\min \frac {x^3} {(y+3)^3} + \frac {y^3} {(x+3)^3}-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
under the constraints $$(x+1)(y+1)=4, x \ge 0, y \ge 0 . $$
Solving it with Mathematica by

```
Minimize[ 32 x^3/(y + 3)^3 + 32 y^3/(x + 3)^3 - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], 
 (x + 1)*(y + 1) == 4 && x >= 0 && y >= 0, {x, y}]
```

we obtain:

```
{1 - \sqrt{2}, {x -> 1, y -> 1}}
```

i.e. $\{a=b,b=c\}.$ One may play with Lagrange multipliers to this end.

---

**Addition.** For each nonnegative $x$ and for each nonnegative $y$ the inequality
  $$ \frac {x^3} {(y+3)^3} + \frac {y^3} {(x+3)^3}-\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \ge 2\sqrt{\frac {x^3y^3} {(x+3)^3(y+3)^3}}-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$ holds.
  The equality takes place iff $\frac {x^3} {(y+3)^3} =\frac {y^3} {(x+3)^3}.$ This implies $x=y$ because the function $f(x):=x^3(x+3)^3$ increases for nonnegative $x$. Taking into account $(x + 1)(y + 1) =4$, we obtain the optimal solution $\{x=1, y=1\}$.

Comment: Is there any "pure" solution for this, such as using primary popular inequality? Your solution is clearly right, but it's not proper for high school student...

Comment: If a high school student knows elements of calculus, then the one can substitute $y= \frac 4 {x+1} -1$ and find the minimum of a function of single variable $x$. An elementary solution  was not demanded in your question.

Comment: OH sorry, it's my fault. I editted my question. Can you try to think about it? I really appreciate.

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by elementary popular inequalities?

Comment: I mean we can use popular inequality such as Cauchy, B-C-S,...I don't understand what you mean by "Solving it with Mathematica". Is this a tool or an algorithm.One more thing, the degree of denominator in my problem is 3, not 1 as you rewrite in line 3.

Comment: I found a solution but unfortunately it's not beautiful at all. In particular, it demands too much calculation.

Comment: Look at the addition to my answer.

Comment: Still don't get what you mean. How can you find the minimum of $$2\sqrt{\frac{x^{3}y^{3}}{(x+3)^{3}(y+3)^{3}}} - \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}$$ ?

Comment: Could you present your proof in SE Matematics?

Comment: The target function is estimated from below. This is achieved iff $x=y$, i. e.  if $x \ne y$ the one can be decreased, not changing $x^2+y^2.$ E. g., if $x>y,$ then I may decrease $x$ and increase $y$ up to $x=y$, obtaining the target function $$F(r):=\frac {\frac{r^3} {\sqrt{2}}} {\left(\frac r {\sqrt{2}}+3\right)^3} - r,$$ where $r:=\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}.$  I note that $F(r)$ increases for $r\ge \sqrt{2}, r \le 3$ because $F'(r)$ is positive there (The bounds for $r$ arise from the constraints.).  Taking into account the constraint $(x+1)(y+1)=4,$ I obtain $x=1,y=1$ for $r=\sqrt{2}.$

Comment: I think there's something in your proof. In case $x \neq y$, and you decrease one and increase the other to not change $\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}$, the equation $(x+1)(y+1)=4$ may not be true at all. So you can't change the expression into single-variable function like the way you did.

Comment: Read carefully my proof. If $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r$, then  the target function is greater than or equal to  $F(r)$. The constraints imply $r \ge \sqrt{2},\, r \le3$. Also $F(r)$ is increasing there. I don't change $x$ and $y$ s.t. $(x+1)(y+1)=4$ and $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r$.

Comment: @user64494 A question: Although by AM-GM, you have (you missed $32$ in your answer) $$\frac {32x^3} {(y+3)^3} + \frac {32y^3} {(x+3)^3}-\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \ge 64\sqrt{\frac {x^3y^3} {(x+3)^3(y+3)^3}}-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$$
However, the minimum of $64\sqrt{\frac {x^3y^3} {(x+3)^3(y+3)^3}}-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is not $1 - \sqrt 2$.
For example, when $x = 0, y = 3$ (satisfying $(x+1)(y+1)=4$), we have
$64\sqrt{\frac {x^3y^3} {(x+3)^3(y+3)^3}}-\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = -3 < 1- \sqrt 2$.

Comment: @user64494 I think that, in general, if we have $f(x, y) \ge g(x,y)$ where equality takes place iff $x=x_0, y= y_0$, we can not conclude that the minimum of $f(x, y)$ is equal to $f(x_0, y_0)$.

Answer (score 0):

*Remark*: Here is a solution without calculus.

Let $x = a/c$ and $y = b/c$.
The condition becomes $(x + 1)(y + 1) = 4$.
We need to find the minimum of
$$P = \frac{32x^3}{(y+3)^3} + \frac{32y^3}{(x+3)^3} - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}.$$

**Answer**. The minimum is $1 - \sqrt 2$ when $x = y = 1$.

**Proof**.

From $(x+1)(y+1)=4$, we have
$$xy + x + y = 3. \tag{1}$$

Using $(x+y)^2\ge 4xy$ and (1), we have
$(x + y)^2/4 + x+ y \ge 3$ which results in
$$x + y \ge 2.\tag{2}$$

Using (1), we have
$$x^2 + y^2 = (x + y)^2 - 2xy
= (x + y)^2 - 2(3 - x - y) = 
(x + y + 1)^2 - 7 \tag{3}$$
and
$$\frac{x}{y+3} + \frac{y}{x+3}- \frac{x + y - 1}{2} = \frac{(x + y + 3)(3-x-y-xy)}{2(x+3)(y+3)} = 0.\tag{4}$$
(*Note*: How to find (4)? Originally, I let $p = x + y, q = xy$
to obtain $\frac{x}{y+3} + \frac{y}{x+3} = \frac{p^2 - 2q + 3p}{q+ 3p + 9}$
which is simply $\frac{p - 1}{2}$ when inserting $q = 3- p$.)

$\phantom{2}$

Using $u^3 + v^3 - \frac14 (u + v)^3 = \frac34(u+v)(u-v)^2\ge 0$ for all $u, v \ge 0$, using (2) and (3) and (4), we have
\begin{align*}
 P &\ge 32 \cdot \frac14\left(\frac{x}{y+3} + \frac{y}{x+3}\right)^3 - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\\[6pt]
 &= 8\left(\frac{x + y - 1}{2}\right)^3 - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\\
 &= (x + y - 1)^3 - \sqrt{(x+y+1)^2 - 7}\\
 &\ge 3(x + y - 1) - 2 - \sqrt{(x+y+1)^2 - 7} \tag{5}\\
 &= 1 - \sqrt 2 + 3(x + y - 2) - (\sqrt{(x+y+1)^2 - 7} - \sqrt 2)\\
 &= 1 - \sqrt 2 + 3(x + y - 2) - \frac{(x + y + 1)^2 - 7 - 2}{\sqrt{(x+y+1)^2 - 7} + \sqrt 2}\\[6pt]
 &= 1 - \sqrt 2 + (x + y - 2)\left(3 -  \frac{x + y + 4}{\sqrt{(x+y+1)^2 - 7} + \sqrt 2}\right)\\
 &\ge 1 - \sqrt 2 + (x + y - 2)\left(3 -  \frac{3 + 4}{\sqrt{(2+1)^2 - 7} + \sqrt 2}\right) \tag{6}\\
 &= 1 - \sqrt 2 + (x +y - 2)\left(3 - \frac{7}{4}\sqrt 2\right)\\
 &\ge 1 - \sqrt 2
\end{align*}
where in (5) we use
$(x + y - 1)^3 - [3(x + y - 1) - 2] = (x + y - 2)^2(x + y + 1) \ge 0$,
and in (6) we use $2 \le x+y \le 3$.

Also, $P = 1 - \sqrt 2$ when $x = y = 1$.

Thus, the minimum of $P$ is $1 - \sqrt 2$.

We are done.